# Unable to sign a message on geth Console

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I have two accounts on my geth node . The geth node is syncing with the Ropsten testnet . I executed the following commands

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[1],'Test');
```

The result was true

After this I tried to sign data by using the following :-

```
web3.eth.sign("Hello world", eth.accounts[1]).then(console.log);
```

But can see an error message "invalid address"

What could be causing this error ? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax for `eth.sign` is  `web3.eth.sign(address, dataToSign, [, callback])`, you switched address and data, also make sure to give hex string or use `web3.toHex` for dataToSign parameter.